# May I create multiple refunds for one PaymentIntent with Stripe?

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, stripe-payments

I have a `Spring Boot/Angular` application and using **Stripe for payments**. Right now I'm moving from using Charges to **PaymentIntent**, and my question is: **Is it possible to do multiple refunds for one PaymentIntent?** For example, if I use one `PaymentIntent` for multiple products, can I later create 2, 3 or more refunds for this particular PaymentIntent.

This was easy with Charges since I was creating separate Charge for every product, but now I need to capture payment at once (with 3d verification). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A PaymentIntent contains a [list of charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-charges) associated with it. To do multiple refunds, you'd just create a refund and specify an amount that's less than the [total amount](https://stripe.com/docs/api/refunds/create#create_refund-amount), using the charge from the PaymentIntent.

Comment: Just to add, in the list is only last charge related to the paymentIntent, but this is basically the solution...

Comment: Today there's a method for this. In the current Stipe Java SDK you can do the following if you have the paymentIntent: `paymentIntent.getCharges().getData().get(0).getAmountRefunded();`
There is only one charge as mentioned above which sums everything up.